# Updating React state with Immutable

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, immutable.js

I'm trying to update my regular React state through Immutable, and got into some few issues. The state isn't deeply nested or it isn't nested from anything other than the state itself, such as `{ "username" : "keyval" : null}}`

This means I could not do something such as `username.update('keyval', something)`, instead I need another approach. Its a rather easy question, I just don't know how to do it. Here's how my setState looks like, which I want to make an Immutable setState action.

```
handleUpdatePassword(event) {
    event.persist()
    this.setState(({password}) => ({
      password: state.update('password', event.target.value)
      })
    );
  }
```

And here is the error I get when trying:

```
   handleUpdatePassword(event) {
        event.persist()
        this.setState({
          password: state.update('password', event.target.value)
          })
      }
```

[image: sad]
Also, This works, but I get this error: `this.state.updater is not a function`

```
handleUpdateUsername(event) {
    console.log(this.state)
    event.persist()
    this.setState({
      username: this.state.update('username', event.target.value)
      })
  }
```

Comment: FWIW, I´ve looked into this as well, [link](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state) but it is misleading, as most of the state isn't dested for basic components.

Comment: I think `this.state` should be `Immutable.Map`

Comment: It is, declared before. Was kinda obvious :p

Comment: It looked like you had a simple JS object. Then look at this: `this.state.updater is not a fucntion` why updater? Why not update? And this sentence `lso, This works, but I get this error: this.state.updater is not a function` makes no sense. It either works or throws.

Comment: funny, cause if I use this.state.set(...) it renders once, and on second keystroke it throws. I can see my state being updated too

Comment: What is the code of setState?

Comment: this.state = Map({ username: "", password: ""})

Comment: So you do not even use the parameter in setState?

Comment: the code of setState is the ones on the picture

Comment: tried that earlier, but it didn't work, ( first example )

Comment: Uh oh, sorry, so you are in a class created by `React.createClass`. setState is library function.

Comment: nope, is an ES6 class, declared in the constructor

Comment: Ok, then where is setState declared?

Comment: straight after the constructor

Comment: I'm using breakpoints in GChrome now, and when it gets the state in the parameter in setState, password is undefined

Comment: I think you should update the question with all the information we discussed here. You know, its easier for us to see whats going on when we get a code that is complete. In fact, the best is an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`state` should be a plain JavaScript object as you can read in the [documentation](https://github.com/facebook/immutable-js/wiki/Immutable-as-React-state).

> Note that state must be a plain JS object, and not an Immutable
>   collection, because React's setState API expects an object literal and
>   will merge it (Object.assign) with the previous state.

Your initial state should look something like this

```
constructor(){
     ...
     this.state = {data: Map({ password: "", username: ""})}
}
```

After that, you'll be able to update the data like this

```
handleUpdatePassword(event) {
 this.setState(({data}) => ({
      data: data.update('password', password =>  event.target.value)
    }));
}
```

Comment: yeah, correct. I want to avoid having an nested obj where I don't need it to be though, so I want state to be an immutable

Comment: I'll mark this as solved, perhaps @lee-byron could help with having the entire state immutable? :)

Comment: Here's a quick codepen illustrating this: [React+ImmutableJS State: Change to Chuck Norris](https://codepen.io/codekiln/pen/ZXoXaa?editors=0011)

Answer (score 0):

You are creating explicit objects. Just let ImmutableJS do it for you.

```
class YourReactComp extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    this.state = Immutable.Map({"username": ""});
  }
  handleUpdateUsername(event) {
    console.log(this.state)
    event.persist()
    this.setState(this.state.set("username", event.target.value));
  }
}
```

EDIT

`ImmutableMap.update(key, updater)` uses a callback to set the value, you want `ImmutableMap.set(key, newValue)` here.

Comment: Then look closely. Your first code gives a lambda to setstate (makes no sense) the second gives a regular JS object, and in the inside you call update with the wrong params. Your third example is exactly the same as the second.

Comment: Sorry, not exactly. In the second you do not use the state stored in the component, but one from the scope, which we really don't have a way to figure out if its declared or not because we don't see your whole code.

Comment: Regardless, using your code, I get "this.state.set(...) is not a function"

Comment: Well, that must be for the reason QoP told us.

Comment: yeah, and that's what I want to avoid :(((